# make GCC's ASM label available for tokenization

Tags: c++, c, gcc, assembly, build

so, let me warn you guys, i don't really know much about how GCC's build process uses the preprocessor. specifically the naming of assembly symbols for the assembler and consequently the linker.

but, from what i gather after the abstract syntax tree has been created by the compiler, the preprocessor is called for the second time by the assembler to create the symbol labels to figure out all the static dependencies and whatnot...

now, this may sound weird, but i need to access the ASM labels and use them in code and *stringify them using the same preprocessor* (#str), to be specific. i could manually do the labeling using **asm**. but i need to access the ones internally defined by the build

of course, from the point of view of a programmer compiling in GCC, the preprocessor is only called once at the very start to create a very, very long source file. the asm labeling happens afterwards. so is it even possible to do it by the book within GCC, at least?

Comment: ok, exactly why i want to do this?? i want to implement an "in-macro" way of redefining other macros. so i've been playing around: _Pragma("redefine_extname X   val")

Comment: problem is that it only does it for the assembly labels. so i thought if there is an off chance that the preprocessor may be doing this BEFORE the compiler turns the code to an abstract syntax tree, then i might be able to access the symbol names standardly, at least under GCC.

Comment: i know, it's a dumb idea.

Answer (score 0):

**gcc -c foo.c** will give you the obj file. Use objdum -S foo.o to see the asm code.

For Example:

```
$gcc -c foo.c
$objdump -S foo.o

foo.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <test>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
   8:   48 89 7d f8             mov    %rdi,-0x8(%rbp)
   c:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
  10:   8b 10                   mov    (%rax),%edx
  12:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  17:   89 d6                   mov    %edx,%esi
  19:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  1c:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  21:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  26 <test+0x26>
  26:   c9                      leaveq
  27:   c3                      retq
```